# Is there a way to deploy angular app on two domains with separate login pages?

Tags: angular, deployment, angular5, multiple-domains

We have an angular app and there're two urls (for example, auth/login and internal/auth/login ) for logging in for two group of users. The app is already deployed on the server and can access to both pages without a problem.

And we need to deploy the app to two different domains for two group of users as well ( still use the same hosting but different domains). Is there a way to achieve it without separating the app into two( two project folders )?

Comment: An application is a folder with files. If you create two applications with two domains, then you have two folders and to applications. I wouldn't advise keeping a single application on logging according to the domain name.

Comment: @trichetriche Thanks for your suggestion. It was solved by using environment to separate the deployment plan for different domain and put two folders for each domain.